# How can change the display of the product images on the PDP? Spartacus

Tags: angularjs, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Im new with spartacus and angular and I am trying to change the style that spartacus brings by default in the PDP, more specifically the images component. I want to delete the carrousel and put the images one on top of the other, as it appears in the capybara theme. i have made a new component for this but i can't loop over the images, I can't find in the product object where the images are.

I've tried  {{product.images}}, {{product.images.GALLERY[0].product}}    {{product.images.GALLERY[0].thumbnail}} and i get [Object Object]

thanks in advance!

[look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLzZV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the Spartacus's `ProductImagesComponent` with your new created component, something like this:

```
provideConfig(<CmsConfig>{
      cmsComponents: {
        ProductImagesComponent: {
          component: YourNewProductImageComponent,
        },
      },
    }),
```

In your new created component, you can call `this.currentProductService.getProduct()` to get the current product. Images can be found in {{product.images.GALLERY[x].product}} .

Comment: thanks for your response!  and sorry to bother again. But how can i iterate over the GALLERY array to show every picture? i've tried *ngFor but i dont know how to do it and didnt work. 



<div *ngFor="let images of product.images.GALLERY[].product.url">
    <img [src]="images">
  </div>

Answer (score 1):

Try using the cx-media tag:

```
<cx-media class="cx-product-image"
                  [container]="product.images?.PRIMARY"
                  format="product"
                  [alt]="product.summary">
</cx-media>
```